# Why Js works only on reload using Safari and Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, safari

I'm working with a Rails 5 app.
The app works properly on chrome and firefox but JS is not working on Safari. At first load the JS is not working but if I reload the page it worked. This is happening only in production mode.

I have no network requests errors according to the safari console. And all assets looks to be properly loaded at first.

Any Idea ?

If you need other informations to be able to help me, please ask

Comment: I use Safari & Firefox, they both work well with all Rails apps. Have you checked the Safari settings? What is in the production logs?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? If a page reload fixes things, it could be the event to fire the js isn't being triggered due to this.

Comment: Yes I use turbolinks. Do I have to disable it or doing something in particular ?

Comment: @ThorTL67 logs are ok, those are the same logs for chrome and safari